# UIKit UIView Scrolling when scroll collection view

Tags: scroll, uiview, uikit

I have an app where there's a collection view in it. But can I scroll the UIView as the colview container as well when I scroll the collection view? For further info please check image below:

[Click here for the page image please](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgV1F.png)

So I want the yellow UIView is scrolling to top as well covering the header when I scroll the collection view. Is it possible? If it is, how can I do that? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UICollectionView is subclass of UIScrollView. You can listen to scrolling delegate methods for collectionView.
So on scrolling collectionView, you'll get callback in scrollViewDidScroll and using contentOffset value of scrollView you can change properties of headerView.